# Why VBA code stops running after use .PasteExcelTable

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ms-word

i'm trying to automate a multiple creation of word documments interacting it with an excel data that i have, the problem is when the code gets to the function añadirTablas and executes .PasteExcelTable, it adds the table in Word and after it stops code running without showing an error. This is the code i'm using:

```
Sub insertarInfoTitulos()

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE TITULOS")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE CUENTAS BANCARIAS")

    rArchivo = "D:\Modelo carta Circularización Tìtulos.docx"

    etiqWord = Array("[Ciudad]", "[Ciudad_PA]", "[fecha]", "[Dirigido a]", "[Direccion]", "[dia]", "[mes]", _
                     "[año]", "[Nombre PA]")
    arrTitulos = informacionAñadir(sh1)
    corteInf = sh1.Cells(1, 2)
    fecha = sh1.Cells(2, 2)
    ciudad = sh1.Cells(3, 2)

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    objWord.Documents.Open rArchivo
    objWord.Visible = True

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrTitulos, 1)

        For j = 0 To UBound(etiqWord)
    
            With objWord.Selection.Find
            
                .Text = etiqWord(j)
            
                If etiqWord(j) = "[Ciudad]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = ciudad
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[fecha]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = fecha
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[dia]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = Day(corteInf)
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[mes]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = UCase(Left(Format(corteInf, "mmmm"), 1)) & Mid(Format(corteInf, "mmmm"), 2)
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[año]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = Year(corteInf)
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[Direccion]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = arrTitulos(i, 5)
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[Dirigido a]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = arrTitulos(i, 4)
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[Ciudad_PA]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = arrTitulos(i, 6)
                ElseIf etiqWord(j) = "[Nombre PA]" Then
                    .Replacement.Text = arrTitulos(i, 1)
                End If
                
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            
            End With
    
        Next j
        
        codNeg = arrTitulos(i, 0)
        añadirTablas sh1, objWord, codNeg
        
    Next i

End Sub

Function informacionAñadir(sh As Variant)

    lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = sh.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim arr(100, 100) As Variant
            
    If sh.AutoFilterMode Then
    
        sh.AutoFilterMode = False
        sh.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, lastCol)).AutoFilter
        sh.Cells(4, 1).Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes

    Else
        sh.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, lastCol)).AutoFilter
        sh.Cells(4, 1).Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    
    End If
            
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        For j = 1 To lastCol
            arr(i - 4, j - 1) = sh.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    informacionAñadir = ReDimPreserve(arr, i - 5, j - 1)

End Function

Sub añadirTablas(sh As Variant, objWord As Variant, codNeg As Variant)

    sh.Cells(4, 1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=codNeg

    lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = sh.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set tblRange = sh.Range(Cells(4, 10), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

    tblRange.Copy

    objWord.Application.Selection.Find.Execute "[Tabla 1]"

    With objWord.Selection
        .PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=True, _
        RTF:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

I tried to search issues similar to this but i didn't find anything. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next`, which is probably hiding the error(s) occurring. Then report back on the error message(s) and line(s) that cause them.

Comment: Also, get used to using Option Explicit at the top of your code and then declaring all your variables.

Comment: 0

If you click in the thin column just to the left of End Sub you can create a break to pause the program but hold the variables so you can maybe see what variable is not what you expected by hovering over them. If there is no next i to process it looks your code should stop. You have used i and j as variables a couple of times so they maybe changing during the process from what you expect them to be.